# Can I change my play order based on date?

Tags: video, filesystems, music

I noticed when playing videos/music (using media player classic) and viewing  image files, JPEGs, GIFs (using Windows Photo Viewer for JPEGs, and 7GIF for .gif extension files since Windows 7 doesn't have a way to view .gif files), that the next file played in the folder is always based on alphabetical order.

Can I change it so that the next file that loads when I hit the right arrow key for the next image, or when I press the key for next file for a video player, that it will play the next file based on date, since I often order my files by date, so the latest one downloaded is at the top?

I would like to play/view files from newest to oldest, is this possible?

OS: Windows 7 x64, programs used to view files:
Windows Photo Viewer, 7GIF, Media Player Classic.

Example with a few files sorted by date.
(folder set to sort files by Date)

```
file name ___________________Date modified
Aizen x Riven movie.mp4______12/23/2014
Yellow Objects.mp4__________ 12/16/2014
Jailbait 2014.mp4____________11/28/2014
Bravely Default Movie.mp4____10/31/2014
Zebra Go Home.mp4____________10/16/2014
```

Using media player classic, if I start by playing "Aizen x Riven movie", and I press the next key (page down), next file (ctrl + page down), or skip forward button, they all will play things of the folder above in alphabetical order. So from aizen...... .mp4, to bravely, then jailbait, yellow obj, then finally zebra go home.mp4.

My question is can I make some changes to my computer that will allow me to play from newest file to oldest, so playing down the list by date as shown in the folder example above. Another would be, to ask if there was a setting on Windows 7 to view image files based on date as well.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have left out some key details. What OS are you using? What program are you using to view your files (Windows Explorer)? You do realize videos, music and images are often executed by different programs, right? So, please clarify what you mean when you ask if you "*hit the right arrow key...it will play the next file based on date*".

Comment: I have made an edit to my question, how may i request for it be taken off hold?

Comment: Looks like it has already been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the other two, but I find that Windows Photo Viewer
will navigate a folder in the order that the folder was sorted in
when Photo Viewer started.  So, sort your Pictures folder by date,

[image: Pictures folder, sorted by date]

double-click on a file, and start viewing.  Note:
changing the directory sort order after Photo Viewer has started has no effect.

Also, Photo Viewer is capable of displaying GIFs
(although it does not display animated GIFs as animated;
it shows only the first frame). 
You might need to put your GIFs into the same folder
with at least one JPEG or PNG, and then click on the non-GIF to get it started,
but you should be able to browse to the GIFs.

Also, Internet Explorer can display GIFs — even animated ones —
but it's not good about displaying sequential files from a folder.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I really want to know if this can be done with video files, via media player classic, or any particular player that can do as described.